# Shortening this Code to process nested tuple even further without the use of max()

Tags: code-golf, array, tips, python

I have the code:

```python
marks = tuple(tuple((input("Enter subject: "), input("Enter marks: "))) for _ in range(int(input("Enter number of tuples: "))))
print(tuple((s[:3].upper(), max(int(m) for t, m in marks if t == s)) for s in set(t for t, m in marks)))
```

```python
#INPUT
(("Physics",131),("Chemistry",30),("Physics",100),("Computers",50),("Chemistry",20))
#OUTPUT
(('COM', 50), ('PHY', 131), ('CHE', 30))
```

As you can see, the output is a nested tuple of the first three capitalized letters of the subject and the maximum mark given for each subject.

You can assume that Physics, Chemistry and Computers are the only subjects that the user inputs, and that they always use the same spelling for the subjects.

The order of the subjects in the output does not matter.

Is there anyway I can do the same without using the max function? The length of the code should optimally be at 2 lines or if at all possible, a single line. The maximum limit of the number of lines of code is 3.

The solution should try to contain no built in functions if possible. Functions like sort(), sorted() and max() are strictly not allowed.

Comment: You can replace `tuple(x)` with `(*x,)` to save some bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python](https://www.python.org),  <del>204</del> 188 bytes

-16 bytes thanks to @WheatWizard

```python
m=[*((input("Enter subject: "),int(input("Enter marks: ")))for _ in'*'*int(input("Enter number of tuples: ")))]
print((*((i[:3].upper(),j)for i,j in m if all(y!=i or z<=j for y,z in m)),))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBNasMwEEb3OsU0XURj1OLUBEqIoBC67z6EkqQylmPJQj9Q5yrdeNOeohfJbSrZKW3ISqDvzfs0-vgyna9a3fefwZd3j6dvxdcZpVKb4OnkWXthwYVdLfZ-ARNkUvvLUG3twaUIsWwtvILU02yaXXE6qF082hJ8MI04j2yIsQmlqXO9KDb3wRhhKbJ60ElWRyEokCVsm4Z2N1xCvD8ueQ0J6NhxABAZ4nmHt9tROhRR6i688cHvVA2zniWxHldIDR44B4c4pC5FTkTNNYy_Xf3paU5eqs7JvSOzYkZWlVDSeduRIv8L8pysWhV_Q1hH5vk_6iEfRT8)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 212 bytes

1 line

```python
print((*[m:=[*((input("Enter subject: "),int(input("Enter marks: ")))for _ in range(int(input("Enter number of tuples: "))))]][:0],*((i[0][:3].upper(),i[1])for i in m if all(z[0]!=i[0]or z[1]<=i[1]for z in m)),))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDNSsQwFEb3eYrruLkZqqSWASkWhMG9-1KkM6Y22qQhP2D7Km660SdyM29j0o7oMKsEvnO_k5uPLz24tlfT9Oldc3V7-NZGKIe4LmVelGtEobR3uHpQjhuwfvfK9y6HFU0idhLK2rzZGFHa9AaeQCgwtXrheIYqL3fh6BtwXnf8OEWrqsxZlURrycI9q6691txgsJVpNdeKWCtBNFB3HY6BuygiHaIxMHdFJCM4ziClCaXH3Z4vl-VmJ6I9EYTnv6OEOOmSKFDLQtHkoCjAUjqnNkaWh5pzmP66psP9hjy2gxV7S9IsJduWS2GdGUjG_gLGyLaX4WO4sWTD_lE3bCn6AQ)

These are just some trivial golfs on your approach. It could probably be made much shorter. If there are ties this will print both.

Comment: This is insane, thank you. I never thought about using the all operator that way

Comment: Here's [202 bytes and 3 lines](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBToQwEIbvfYqxXjouGpBsYogkJhvv3gkxsFukQgtpSwK8ihcu-jC-wb6NLbtGjdf5v_n-zLx99JOtO7Us74Otru-On03aFrI8FDAmQvWDZfRRWa6BbsYNTYAikWl2xVjDqBnKV763FAOhrB_IQjeGImLVaXgGoUAX6oWzc6wGWTpTV4Ed-pavJOak1z5nzimyMM-SOL8Z-p5r5rxZlK8y4WUSRAVF27LZcRepp100O-Y-9aQH5xVEDBDPFx0uTwVrJ2PmTwHIYmQS_KYNfIFb9kf4JgtpCgZxTY2PDHea_zB-dy3Hhy15qicj9oZEcUR2NZfCWD2ROPwJwpDsOul-y7Uh2_AXdRueRF8)

Comment: You can save bytes on all of the options by [pattern matching tuples](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBBTsMwEEX3PsVgNh5qUEpUCUUKQqrYs68qlLQOcRI7lu1ISa_CJhs4BvfobYjTooLYzn_zvsfvn2bwZavH8aPzxe3D8atOm0zl-wz6RGrTeUaftRcW6KJf0AQoEpVubhirGXVdXomdp8il9mGgMls7iohFa-EVpAab6TfBzrHuVD6Z2gJ8Zxoxk7glxoacTU65SeLtXWeMsAx5NWskr4JIgSwgaxomr9IBpnn1mB4gAAM_zAAiRzxfsb8-SecextwfL6isZ2re9TyIp-Xw8NDgIU3BIc6pC5ETk-Y_jD9d4_FpRV7KwcmdI8t4SdalUNJ5O5A4ugRRRNatmv5TWEdW0S_qPjqJvgE)

Comment: [No need to use `range` if you just need a list of the proper size](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBBTsMwEEX3PsVgNp7UoJSqEopkhFSxZ19VKGkdxUmcRLYjJb0Km2zgENykt8FOiyhiO__N-x6_f3ajK9pmmj56l989nr4qUac6O6QwJKrpesfoS-OkAboYFjQBikSLbcRYxajts1LuHUWuGhcGOjWVpYiYtwbeQDU0otEla3qdeU2bg-u7Ws7YjnQmxMz71DZZ7e77rpOGIS9nheKll4AGlUNa10zdiBH8vHwSRwjAyI8zgMgRLxccbs_SuYYx-8cLOh2YnncdD2K_HB4dGhwIARZxTm2IrPSa_zD-dE2n5zV5LUar9pYsV0uyKaRW1pmRrOLfII7JptX-L6WxZB1fUQ_xWfQN)

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that OP wanted to prioritize less lines over less bytes

Comment: @mousetail Yes, I interpreted it as that as well.  Two of the golfs work on all of the answers.  And they did say 3 lines was ok.

Comment: No need to do `[*(x for x in x)]`, just do `[x for x in x]`

Answer (score 5):

## 1 line, <s>180</s> <s>173</s> 171 bytes

*7 bytes saved thanks to Jonathan Allen*

```python
exec("x={}\n"+"if x.get(a:=input('Enter subject: ')[:3].upper(),b:=int(input('Enter marks: ')))<=b:x[a]=b\n"*int(input("Enter number of tuples: "))+"print((*x.items(),))")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY9BTsMwEEX3PoVlFvW0EKVElVCEJaSKPfvSRdI6xIAdyx5LjhAnYZMNbDhRb4PTIJWK1Wj038z__-PL9th2Zhg-AzZXN4dvGeWOsyje3h8NWzDV0Jg9SeRVKZSxAfns3qB01If6We6wpDPYlMU2C9ZKx-GyHjnkZ6yu3IsfSYBbUZdxU21Fnd7PTySbSBN0nUbXUAz2VaYjBrBg1o0kn8dModQ-2QAw-I28v5jk4wXn_ixO8o5c06ZzFNNClZnS0FQMqRDUAxxVP0o-FcX_cMo9eQ2HuxV5aHuvdp4siyVZt1Irj64nRX4S8pysO51qSefJKv9DXefTox8)

## 3 lines, <s>171</s> <s>163</s> 160 bytes

*8 bytes saved thanks to Jonathan Allen*

```python
x,i,e={},input,'Enter '
exec("if x.get(a:=i(e+'subject: ')[:3].upper(),b:=int(i(e+'marks: ')))<=b:x[a]=b\n"*int(i(e+"number of tuples: ")))
print((*x.items(),))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBSsQwEIbveYpQD03WWrqWBSkGhMW793UPbZ3aqElDMoEU8Um89KLvtG9j2nVR8Th8H_P_M--fZsR-0NP04bG7uDpMIZMZiNe3TGrjMUtvNYKlKYEALUtkR0P-CMjqSkgG56nzzRO0WNGU76pyn3tjwDKeNZFrZIujavvsZoPza9FUYVfvRXOvk9XJSLRXTUwZOorevECUkygTY2eDrUIuEZSLazn_7vlwdoSLz5j7E05VHZii3WApxoFKTZcONNZHKgR1nC_UzcjFc_C_zE9Z0-FmQ-760cnWkXW5JtselHRoR1IWP6AoyHZQ8WdgHdkUv6zL4rjoCw)

Here's another approach that yields fewer bytes.  It can be done in 1, 2 or 3 lines, with more lines enabling shorter overall programs.  There's probably still even some improvements to be made here.

Comment: Depending on the rules, you might be able to replace the last `print` with `i`

Comment: I mean, the second one can be one line too, just replace the newlines with semicolons

Comment: @naffetS I don't think that's really what is meant by lines.

Comment: [158](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBSsQwEIbveYpQWZostXQtC1IMCIt37-se2praqElDZgIp4pMI0ou-076N2a6Lisfh-_j_mXn7tCP2g5mmD4_d-eX-PWQqk-LlNVPGeszSG4PS0QVUNCUyyJYlqqMhf5DI6kooJhcp-OZRtpjybVXucm-tdIxnTaQG2Wzo2j1Byjm_Ek0VtvVONHcmWZ54YrxuYsvQUfT2WUISVWLdgbNlyBVKDTGS8-8t78-OcLYZgz_FVNeBadoNjmIcqDJ07qdxcaRCUOB8pnBAEA_B_zI_dU376zW57UdQLZBVuSKbXmoF6EZSFj-gKMhm0PFj0gFZF7-si-IY9AU) for the second one